# How to link Taxonomy term Image to taxonomy term page in the Drupal View?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-theming, drupal-taxonomy

I would like to link the taxonomy term image to the taxonomy term page, the option is available in the field of the taxonomy term name but not for the taxonomy term image in the view...

Thanks!

Comment: pls provide more info can't  seem to understand what you want

Comment: What version of Drupal and Views are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of your views module you can try following solutions:

1. Add your taxonomy picture as a field and set it 'link to taxonomy page'
2. First add your taxonomy link as a field and set 'hide this filed'; than Add your taxonomy picture as the second field and go to field Rewrite and set 'provide link to this field' (or similar) and add the first field into the link input filed there. (you might need to install Token Module to do this)